# Heroku app successfully deployed, but receiving application error when opening app

Tags: python, heroku, gunicorn

I was following a [Youtube Tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYwwp.png) on making a WhatsApp bot with Python, Twilio, and flask.
All was good until it was time to deploy the bot on Heroku, The app was successfully deployed but then when I tried to open the app, It failed with the following screen

[image: application error]

After Running `heroku logs --tail`
this is what I got

```
 »   Warning: heroku update available from 7.53.0 to 7.53.1.
2021-05-10T17:05:27.833066+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
2021-05-10T17:05:30.957905+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2021-05-10T17:05:31.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-05-10T17:05:31.056144+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2021-05-10T17:05:31.138486+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-05-10T17:05:31.179296+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-05-10T17:05:37.281917+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
2021-05-10T17:05:40.782645+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2021-05-10T17:05:40.858440+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2021-05-10T17:05:40.962293+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-05-10T17:05:58.300980+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=w28bot.herokuapp.com request_id=c092082c-596c-4e11-9139-38a6353d1b4c fwd="102.166.25.202" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-10T17:06:00.776174+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=w28bot.herokuapp.com request_id=5407d07b-f580-460f-bd67-dec4e694623b fwd="102.166.25.202" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-10T17:12:59.818806+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-05-10T17:13:05.166161+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
2021-05-10T17:13:08.574926+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2021-05-10T17:13:08.649127+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2021-05-10T17:13:08.726439+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-05-10T17:13:11.111267+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=w28bot.herokuapp.com request_id=5f63c437-dc89-45d2-8e2d-6a16fb809bdf fwd="102.166.25.202" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-10T17:13:14.439557+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=w28bot.herokuapp.com request_id=6290cd2f-5238-4f51-a99e-dcd9858177b5 fwd="102.166.25.202" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-10T17:30:17.642449+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=w28bot.herokuapp.com request_id=06e9bf70-d722-4829-8372-a93002291922 fwd="102.167.29.105" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-10T17:30:21.211441+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=w28bot.herokuapp.com request_id=27a55213-c14e-49ff-a6dd-bd627c396050 fwd="102.167.29.105" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-10T17:33:01.744191+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=w28bot.herokuapp.com request_id=95414e5b-7b7e-4a89-9606-092fe2eadf20 fwd="102.167.29.105" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-10T17:33:03.557619+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=w28bot.herokuapp.com request_id=dee3b35e-f733-434f-beb8-7fd58bfd0ead fwd="102.167.29.105" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here's my app.py code

```
from flask import Flask, request
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello, World!"

@app.route("/sms", methods=['POST'])
def sms_reply():
    """Respond to incoming calls with a simple text message."""
    # Fetch the message
    msg = request.form.get('Body')

    # Create reply
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    resp.message("You said: {}".format(msg))

    return str(resp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here's my Procfile

```
web gunicorn app: app
```

Here's my requirements.txt

```
 certifi==2020.12.5
chardet==4.0.0
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==2.10
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
PyJWT==1.7.1
Pysocks==1.7.1
pytz==2021.1
requests==2.25.1
six==1.16.0
twilio==6.58.0
urllib3==1.26.4
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: try this procfile: `web: gunicorn app:app --log-file=-`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a solution by recreating the app again from scratch, Turned out I hadn't installed gunicorn in my virtual environment, which can be achieved by running `$ pip install gunicorn`
I can't tell if that's what exactly caused the rapture but I'm happy now that It can fully run.
Thanks, @KetZoomer for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`gunicorn` is a `pip` package, link: https://pypi.org/project/gunicorn/. In your `requirements.txt` add `gunicorn`.

New `requirements.txt`:

```
certifi==2020.12.5
chardet==4.0.0
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
idna==2.10
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
PyJWT==1.7.1
pytz==2021.1
requests==2.25.1
six==1.16.0
twilio==6.58.0
urllib3==1.26.4
Werkzeug==1.0.1
gunicorn
```

This `Procfile` works for me:

```
web: gunicorn app:app --log-file=-
```

Also make sure you have a `runtime.txt`, for example:

```
python-3.9.5
```

Comment: I actually uploaded the wrong requirements.txt,,, I've updated the question... But even with gunicorn present,,, the error is still there

Comment: I'm really frustrated and I really don't know what to do at this point

Comment: @PrinceErisol try this procfile: `web: gunicorn app:app --log-file=-`

Comment: Can you try running it on your machine and see if you'll figure the problem out, please